# R305 fingerprint sensor with Stm32fo discovery kit

Tags: uart, stm32f0

i am trying to interface a fingerprint sensor([r305](http://www.rhydolabz.com/wiki/?p=15770)) with my stm32f0 discovery kit. I was able to interface and make it work with my arduino and PC using the library and Companion software given in the link but i couldnt make it work with stm kit. The given sensor needs data to be transmitted in packets. I have analysed the packets using packet sniffer in pc and made sample code for handshaking packet in my stm discovery kit.

```
USART2->TDR = 0xef;
Delay_ms(50);
USART2->TDR = 0x01;    
Delay_ms(50);

USART2->TDR = 0xff;
Delay_ms(50);
USART2->TDR = 0xff;
Delay_ms(50);
USART2->TDR = 0xff;
Delay_ms(50);
USART2->TDR = 0xff;
Delay_ms(50);    

USART2->TDR = 0x01;
Delay_ms(50);
USART2->TDR = 0x00;
Delay_ms(50);

USART2->TDR = 0x07;
Delay_ms(50);
USART2->TDR = 0x13;
Delay_ms(50);    

USART2->TDR = 0x00;
Delay_ms(50);
USART2->TDR = 0x00;
Delay_ms(50);        
USART2->TDR = 0x00;
Delay_ms(50);
USART2->TDR = 0x00;
Delay_ms(50);

USART2->TDR = 0x00;
Delay_ms(50);
USART2->TDR = 0x1b;
Delay_ms(500);
```

I gave the output for the code to packet sniffer and was able to view the same hex code as given from the companion software and arduino.

ef 01 ff ff ff ff 01 00 07 13 00 00 00 00 00 1b.

the fingerprint sensor gives output for the same packet generated  from arduino but wont work for my code. What am i doing wrong. Is my delay too much. my baudrate is 57600.I cant seem to find my error. please help and thankyou

Comment: This isn't the correct way to use a USART. It will provide a status flag of some sort to tell you when it's ready for you to load another character into it for transmission; you should use a loop to check this rather than using a fixed delay.

Comment: Yes you are right. i did try using the transfer complete flag but it didnt work for me. thats why i tried the delay function. i will check again.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the post. the problem was solved wen i reduced the delay to 10ms. however it wouldnt work without delay.

```
USART2->TDR = 0xef;
Delay_ms(10);
USART2->TDR = 0x01; 
Delay_ms(10);

USART2->TDR = 0xff;
Delay_ms(10);
USART2->TDR = 0xff;
Delay_ms(10);
USART2->TDR = 0xff;
Delay_ms(10);
USART2->TDR = 0xff;
Delay_ms(10);   

USART2->TDR = 0x01;
Delay_ms(10);
USART2->TDR = 0x00;
Delay_ms(10);

USART2->TDR = 0x07;
Delay_ms(10);
USART2->TDR = 0x13;
Delay_ms(10);   

USART2->TDR = 0x00;
Delay_ms(10);
USART2->TDR = 0x00;
Delay_ms(10);       
USART2->TDR = 0x00;
Delay_ms(10);
USART2->TDR = 0x00;
Delay_ms(10);

USART2->TDR = 0x00;
Delay_ms(10);
USART2->TDR = 0x1b;
Delay_ms(500);
```

Comment: To leave this as an answer for anyone looking in to the original question, can you add a bit more meat to it? Otherwise edit your original question and update with that 10 ms.

Comment: okey i will post the code

Comment: the delay can also be replaced by the statement
while((USART1->ISR & USART_ISR_TC) != USART_ISR_TC);
which is the standard form.